# Problem reading classes from JPMS module in Spring 6

Tags: java, spring, classloader, java-module, spring-context

I have a JPMS application with layer tree. On `Layer C`  I need to create Spring context while Spring framework is located on `Layer B`:

```
boot layer
  |- Layer B with Spring framework.
       |- Layer C where I need to create my context
```

Component:

```
@Component
public class ApplicationContextHolder implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        ApplicationContextHolder.applicationContext = (ConfigurableApplicationContext) applicationContext;
    }

    public static ConfigurableApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return applicationContext;
    }
}
```

Config:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = {
    ApplicationContextHolder.class
})
public class ContextConfig {

}
```

Creating context:

```
    System.out.println("ThreadContextClassLoadere:" + Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
    System.out.println("This classLoader:" + this.getClass().getClassLoader());
    var clazz = this.getClass().getClassLoader().loadClass("org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware");
    System.out.println("RESULT:" + clazz);
    iocContext = new  AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
    iocContext.register(ContextConfig.class);
    iocContext.setClassLoader(this.getClass().getClassLoader());
    iocContext.refresh();
```

Result:

```
ThreadContextClassLoadere:jdk.internal.loader.Loader@63fcbf75
This classLoader:jdk.internal.loader.Loader@63fcbf75
RESULT:interface org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.foo.ContextConfig]
    at spring.context@6.0.13/org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:178)
    at spring.context@6.0.13/org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:415)
    at spring.context@6.0.13/org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:287)
    at spring.context@6.0.13/org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:344)
    at spring.context@6.0.13/org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:115)
    at spring.context@6.0.13/org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:779)
    at spring.context@6.0.13/org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:597)
        ....
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/context/ApplicationContextAware.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at spring.core@6.0.13/org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:211)
    at spring.core@6.0.13/org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.getClassReader(SimpleMetadataReader.java:54)
    at spring.core@6.0.13/org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:48)
    at spring.core@6.0.13/org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:103)
    at spring.core@6.0.13/org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:122)
    at spring.core@6.0.13/org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:81)
    at spring.context@6.0.13/org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.asSourceClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:613)
    at spring.context@6.0.13/org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$SourceClass.getInterfaces(ConfigurationClassParser.java:939)
    at spring.context@6.0.13/org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processInterfaces(ConfigurationClassParser.java:379)
    at spring.context@6.0.13/org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:325)
    at spring.context@6.0.13/org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:243)
    at spring.context@6.0.13/org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:188)
    at spring.context@6.0.13/org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:297)
    at spring.context@6.0.13/org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:243)
    at spring.context@6.0.13/org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:196)
    at spring.context@6.0.13/org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:164)
    ... 16 more
```

As I understand (I may be wrong) Spring uses some other class loader. Could anyone say how to fix it?

Comment: Why are you messing around with classloaders in the firs tplace? Also the `ApplicationContextHolder` is sort of an anti-pattern and shouldn't be used.

Comment: Looking into the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.

Spring loads classes via `getResourceAsStream()` and by default uses `ClassPathResource` with `classLoader.getResourceAsStream(this.absolutePath)`. However, it wont work for the JPMS application. To make it work it is required to use `ModuleResource` (added in Spring 6.1) instead of `ClassPathResource`.

So, it is necessary to create custom `ResourceLoader` that will use `ModuleResource` add set it to context:

```
var iocContext = new  AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
...
var myModuleResourceLoader = ....
iocContext.setResourceLoader(myModuleResourceLoader);
iocContext.refresh();
```